# ¿Aumentar el número máximo de items en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, navigationview, bottombar

¿Alguien sabe cómo aumentar el número máximo de items mostrados en la barra de navegacion (`BottomNavigationView`) de Android Studio 2.3 ?

Quiero poner 8 items en la barra, la aplicacion solo sera para tablets de manera horizontal entonces no le veo problema, ¡ gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El archivo que carga los items dentro del [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) se encuentra en el directorio `res/menu/`, es ahí donde agregas los elementos (`item`):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/menu_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_add" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_navigation"
          android:title="@string/menu_navigation"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_menu" />
 </menu>
```

**Es importante comentar que puede tener de 3 a 5 niveles o items, por lo tanto el numero maximo soportado es 5 (hasta el día de hoy api 25).**

Comment: Si, el detalle es que tengo 8 items y me aparece un error que dice: `Maximum number of items supported by BottomNavigationView is 5.`. Quería saber si se pueden agregar mas de 5 items en la barra de menú. Gracias.

Comment: Una disculpa, veo que deseas 8 items hasta el dìa de hoy API 25 ùnicamente soporta 5 como maximo! =(